# Modify all rows in table

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I'm looking for a more efficient way to modify each row in a table. The table contains 130 000 rows. Each row contains column called `ico` which has to be modified this way:

ico scheme: `xx xxx xxx`

modify: `ico = ico.replace(' ','')`

So ico is changed from `xx xxx xxx` to `xxxxxxxx`.

I tried this way:

```
icos = [x[0] for x in  cur.execute("""SELECT ico FROM companies""").fetchall()]
for ico in icos:
    print ico
    new_ico = ico.replace(' ','')
    cur.execute("""UPDATE companies SET ico=? WHERE ico=?""",(new_ico,ico))
conn.commit()
```

It is very slow (10 rows in 5 seconds). I'm looking for a more efficient way to modify each row from this table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use pure `SQL` and one `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE companies 
SET ico = REPLACE(ico, ' ', '');
```

There is no need for using loop.

You can update records that contains at least one space:

```
UPDATE companies 
SET ico = REPLACE(ico, ' ', '')
WHERE ico LIKE '% %';
```